# What is the Ruby equivalent of python setup.py develop?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am new to ruby and need to debug some ruby app packaged as a gem.

I am using rvm, where I installed the package as a gem, and also have a fresh github checkout of that package. How can I tell my rvm environment to use the code in the github repo instead of the installed gem?

This is the equivalent of `python setup.py develop` for people familiar with python.

> Setuptools allows you to deploy your projects for use in a common directory or staging area, but without copying any files. Thus, you can edit each project’s code in its checkout directory

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, you can.

Check out [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It's the de facto standard to use it.

Comment: I looked a bundler, and did the following: first, create a new gemset inside rvm, then gem install bundler, and then bundler install. It installs all the dependencies as expected, but when I try to run the actually application I ran bundle install in, I get a traceback. Not sure if it is coming from my usage of rvm/gemset/whatever. The traceback is something like "/Users/cournape/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find vagrant (>= 0) amongst [...] (vagrant being the app I am looking into).

Comment: Hm. How are you running vagrant? If you've checked it out, after you bundle install, you should be able to do `bin/vagrant` and run the code you just checked out. You can also do `bundle exec bin/vagrant`, which should be even better, although the gemset should make it irrelevant (`bundle exec` sandboxes the available gems to those in `Gemfile.lock`, but if you have a fresh gemset, it should be virtually the same).

Comment: I think I did something wrong, I don't see the issue anymore. In any case, your advice of using bundle exec works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: actually, a last thing: is there a way to avoid having to be in the app directory ? I'd like to use the dev version of two apps together

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is adding it to your path. Either symlink it in a directory before ruby gems (`/usr/local/bin`?) or add a directory to your path (either `bin/` in your version or create `~/bin`, symlink it in there and add it to your path).

Comment: I actually just tried running bundle exec with the full path, but I get some errors "Could not locate Gemfile". It only disappears  if I am inside the original vagrant directory.

Comment: I don't think you will need bundle exec when you call the executable in vagrant. It should handle loading Bundler on its own.

Comment: What Bundler command is analogous to `python setup.py develop`?

Comment: Not sure what that does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer.

Sometimes gems/packages provide executable. The good thing with `python setup.py develop` is that you will always have the latest version of that executable in your path. It is kind of handy for development. As far as I know Gem does not provide such functionality. To emulate that you can use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and it is how:

- First create a new Gemfile: `bundle init`
- Then edit that file and add the local Gem you are working on (for me it is Nanoc): `gem "nanoc", path: "path/to/local/nanoc"`
- Then to access the executable provided by the Gem you can use bundler that way: `bundle exec nanoc ...`

Here `bundle exec` will take the Gem version from your Gemfile and use it. If that Gem is specified with a `:path` option then it will use that on.

It is sure less convenient that in Python but it is the closest solution I found in Ruby.